# why I cannot access a folder even though I am in the group

Tags: linux

```
> ls -l
...
drwxrwxrwx  70 userA     groupA   71680 Oct 30 09:43 folderA
...

> groups myusername
myusername: groupA

> cd folderA/
-bash: cd: folderA/: Permission denied
```

Question> why I cannot access the folderA even if I am in the group of `groupA`?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a folder on another server?

Comment: Have you just recently become part of groupA, as in, since that shell started?  If so, you will likely need to restart your shell before you actually get the group permissions taking effect even if `groups` shows you as a member of the group

Comment: @Steven, I am not sure whether this folder is on another server

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the results of `ls folderA`?